# How to create a shortcut in C:\?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

Is there a way to create a shortcut that lives in `C:\` (as opposed to my desktop), and points to a folder also in `C:\`?

(I'm not sure whether the tool `shortcut.exe` can do this at all, but in any case, I can't find any versions of it for Windows 7.)

Comment: It's really bad to use files and folders directly on the root folder of C:\ in Windows 7 (really: Vista and later). Standard users have not had write privileges to this folder since Windows 2000, but starting with Vista the operating system starts to get really strict about enforcing this, even if you're logged in as a user with admin rights.

Comment: Related: [Cannot Save in Hard Disk Drive C:](http://superuser.com/questions/342276/cannot-save-in-hard-disk-drive-c)

Comment: What is your end goal? Why have a shortcut to a folder in the same place as the shortcut?

Comment: I downloaded my own mouse cursors, and am saving them in `C:\data_me\app_settings\windows_cursors\`, which is a folder I automatically back up. I have a shortcut in that folder to the built-in cursors, at `C:\Windows\Cursors\`. I need (want) a shortcut from that folder, back to mine, so I can go quickly back and forth between them. That's my use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`C:\` has some access restrictions for security reasons by default, but you can always create a shortcut on the desktop and then cut-paste it into `C:\`. Keep in mind that you may have to adjust shortcut's access privileges using Properties window, Security tab.